# Storing objects in IsolatedStorageSettings

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, object, isolatedstorage

I have an object I want to store in the IsolatedStorageSettings, which I wan't to reuse when the application restarts.

My problem lies in that the code I have written for some reason does not remember the object when trying to access the key upon restarting it.

```
namespace MyNameSpace
{
    public class WindowsPhoneSettings
    {
        private const string SelectedSiteKey = "SelectedSite";
        private IsolatedStorageSettings isolatedStore = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;

        private T RetrieveSetting<T>(string settingKey)
        {
            object settingValue;
            if (isolatedStore.TryGetValue(settingKey, out settingValue))
            {
                return (T)settingValue;
            }
            return default(T);
        }

        public bool AddOrUpdateValue(string Key, Object value)
        {
            bool valueChanged = false;

            if (isolatedStore.Contains(Key))
            {
                if (isolatedStore[Key] != value)
                {
                    isolatedStore[Key] = value;
                    valueChanged = true;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                isolatedStore.Add(Key, value);
                valueChanged = true;
            }
            return valueChanged;
        }

        public MobileSiteDataModel SelectedSite
        {
            get
            {
                return RetrieveSetting<MobileSiteDataModel>(SelectedSiteKey);
            }
            set
            {
                AddOrUpdateValue(SelectedSiteKey, value);
                isolatedStore.Save();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I then instantiate WindowsPhoneSettings in App.xaml.cs and make a public getter and setter for it. To be able to access it in the whole application. Debugging this shows that the right object gets stored in the isolated store, but when closing the app and reopening it isolated store seems to be empty. I have tried this on both the emulator and a real device. As you can see I do call the save method when setting the object.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I'm experiencing the same problem here. Simple objects like strings, bools or ints can be easily saved. However, if I try to save a Song object, everything seems to be deleted on restart (including other values) without any error message. This might be some strange bug and I think it's an internal serialization problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ended up saving the settings to a file in the isolated storage as IsolatedStorageSettings never seemed to work.

So my code ended up like this:

```
public class PhoneSettings
{
    private const string SettingsDir = "settingsDir";
    private const string SettingsFile = "settings.xml";

    public void SetSettings(Settings settings)
    {
        SaveSettingToFile<Settings>(SettingsDir, SettingsFile, settings);
    }

    public Settings GetSettings()
    {
        return RetrieveSettingFromFile<Settings>(SettingsDir, SettingsFile);
    }

    private T RetrieveSettingFromFile<T>(string dir, string file) where T : class
    {
        IsolatedStorageFile isolatedFileStore = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
        if (isolatedFileStore.DirectoryExists(dir))
        {
            try
            {
                using (var stream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream(System.IO.Path.Combine(dir, file), FileMode.Open, isolatedFileStore))
                {
                    return (T)SerializationHelper.DeserializeData<T>(stream);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Could not retrieve file " + dir + "\\" + file + ". With Exception: " + ex.Message);
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    private void SaveSettingToFile<T>(string dir, string file, T data)
    {
        IsolatedStorageFile isolatedFileStore = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
        if (!isolatedFileStore.DirectoryExists(dir))
            isolatedFileStore.CreateDirectory(dir);
        try
        {
            string fn = System.IO.Path.Combine(dir, file);
            if (isolatedFileStore.FileExists(fn)) isolatedFileStore.DeleteFile(fn); //mostly harmless, used because isolatedFileStore is stupid :D

            using (var stream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream(fn, FileMode.CreateNew, FileAccess.ReadWrite, isolatedFileStore))
            {
                SerializationHelper.SerializeData<T>(data, stream);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Could not save file " + dir + "\\" + file + ". With Exception: " + ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

And a settings class just containing the stuff I want to save. This could be:

```
class Settings
{
    private string name;
    private int id;

    public string Name
    {
        get { return name; }
        set { name = value; }
    }

    public int Id
    {
        get { return id; }
        set { id = value; }
    }
}
```

**EDIT:** Sample of how `SerializationHelper` could be implemented

```
public static class SerializationHelper
{
    public static void SerializeData<T>(this T obj, Stream streamObject)
    {
        if (obj == null || streamObject == null)
            return;

        var ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(T));
        ser.WriteObject(streamObject, obj);
    }

    public static T DeserializeData<T>(Stream streamObject)
    {
        if (streamObject == null)
            return default(T);

        var ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(T));
        return (T)ser.ReadObject(streamObject);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is SerializationHelper? is it from some other library? if so can you please mention it.

Comment: SerializationHelper is just a simple class doing the heavy lifting of Serializing and Deserializing objects. In this case it is something a co-worker of mine has written as the implementation we use also needs support for zipping and unzipping files. Although you could use the default `System.Xml.Serialization` methods or some JSON serializer instead.

Comment: Added a sample of SerializationHelper that uses Json.

Answer (score 2):

Objects stored in IsolatedStorageSettings are serialised using the [DataContractSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractserializer%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) and so must be serializable. Ensure they can be or serialize (and deserialize) them yourself before adding to (and after removing from) ISS.

If the items aren't there when trying to retrieve then it may be that they couldn't be added in the first place (due to a serialization issue).

Comment: If I serialize the object on my own and put it in the IsolatedStorageFile it works fine. Just using XmlSerializer to do this and it works without modifying the object I am attempting to serialize.

Comment: I am not sure how to serialize and deserialize the object before saving to the ISS, please provde some link that provides more info, preferably a sample.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code I use to save an object to isolated storage and to load an object from isolated storage -

```
private void saveToIsolatedStorage(string keyname, object value)
{
  IsolatedStorageSettings isolatedStore = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;
  isolatedStore.Remove(keyname);
  isolatedStore.Add(keyname, value);
  isolatedStore.Save();
}

private bool loadObject(string keyname, out object result)
{
  IsolatedStorageSettings isolatedStore = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;

  result = null;
  try
  {
    result = isolatedStore[keyname];
  }
  catch
  {
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

Here is code I use to call the above -

```
private void SaveToIsolatedStorage()
{
  saveToIsolatedStorage("GameData", GameData);
}

private void LoadFromIsolatedStorage()
{
  Object temp;
  if (loadObject("GameData", out temp))
  {
    GameData = (CGameData)temp;
  }
  else
  {
    GameData.Reset();
  }
}
```

Note that the objects I save and restore like this are small and serializable. If my object contains a 2 dimensional array or some other object which is not serializable then I perform my own serialization and deserialization before using iso storage.

Answer (score 0):

What if you changed `RetrieveSetting<T>` to this:

```
private T RetrieveSetting<T>(string settingKey)
{
  T settingValue;
  if(isolatedStore.TryGetValue(settingKey, out settingValue))
  {
    return (T)settingValue;
  }
  return default(T);
}
```

Notice that the object being fetched is being declared as type `T` instead of `object`.

Comment: That did not help. As tried to say in the question, when stepping through with the debugger the IsolatedStorage does not contain any keys at all.

Comment: @Cheesebaron Are you using *Rebuild All* to build the project? Or using the application deployment tool to deploy the XAP file? Both these actions uninstall the existing app and reinstall it, wiping out isolated storage. Use the *Build* option and hit F5 within Visual Studio.