# Isolated Storage(IsolatedStorageSettings) limitations on windows phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I have key-value IsolatedStorage in my app, it contain 4 vars: 2 doubles, 1 bool and 1 ObservableCollection of classes objects.
When I set ObservableCollection to settings and save it like this

```
settings["PlaceMarks"] = PlaceMarks;
```

it overwrites my bool var and on next start I got "key not found" exception

if I write to this settings something like string or number

```
settings["PlaceMarks"] = "string";
```

All is ok. My collection have only three instance of simple classes.
So here is my question why my value disappears? May be it some limitations of IsolatedStorageSettings I didn't know

Answer (score 3):

have you marked those classes that are in Observeable Collection as Serializeable ?

ObservableCollection itself is not marked as serializeable.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604(v=vs.95).aspx

I would suggest you try using a List instead

Answer (score 1):

Only serializable objects (not the case of ObservableCollection) can be saved in the IsolatedStorageSettings.

Objects are serialized using the [DataContractSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractserializer%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) before saving the IsolatedStorageSettings.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/7417049/358596